# Drupal 7 Organic Groups: Cannot Specify Membership Type

Tags: drupal-7, organic-groups

I have an og course group type (not group content). I need to add members to the created groups. I have two groups: students and instructors.

I have added two OG memberships types ("student membership" and "instructor membership") each with a different set of fields that the user should submit when subscribing to a group:
1- Student
2- Instructor

The problem is that the fields that appear are only those in the "default" membership type and neither the members (students or instructors) nor the admin can select the membership type.

I am also struggling to understand where I should specify the membership type for each group type.

Can anyone provide a step by step guide for this?

P.N: I also keep seeing this message Notice: Undefined index: membership_type in og_entity_property_info() (line 236 of /home/devkat/public_html/albinacourses/sites/all/modules/og/og.module).

Thanks a million!

Comment: Hi @perpetual_dream did you manage to find out?